# Postgress SQL Написание Update запроса

Tags: postgresql

Подскажите как сделать подобный Update. Есть таблица, в которой у двух полей нужно поменять значения.
Update "Zakazy"
set product = (m1)
where id = (bagh-be5b-hj3f)

Таким запросом можно сделать по одному соответствию. А мне нужно провести апдейт 10.000 строк, как модифицировать, чтобы можно было частями(например по 100 штук, чтобы не положить базу) делать апдейты?

Comment: Так можно же одним запросом обновить несколько полей:  `Update "Zakazy" set product = (m1), some_field1 = <some value1> where id = (bagh-be5b-hj3f)` . А обновлять несколько строк можно по условию `where` с указанием диапазона строк, напр. использовать `in` ` where id in (bagh-be5b-hj3f, bagh-be5b-hj3f)` или другому критерию, а не по конкретному идентификатору строки.

Comment: Слить все 10000 значений во временную таблицу, да обновить одним махом. Обновление 10000 записей - это ниачём, такой фигнёй базу не положишь.

Comment: Так мне "product" именно с "id" и нужно слить. Насчет id in спасибо, знаю про перечисление. то есть у меня уже есть готовая выборка которую нужно залить в ней два поля
"product" "id" связку которых нужно залить в таблицу Zakazy

Comment: Два поля должны иметь связку-соответствие при update в таблицу Zakazy и так как их много мой запрос пример не подходит для большого кол-ва

Comment: Если нужно брать данные с другой таблицы, то это классический `update from select`. Укажите в вопросе про вторую таблицу (можно создать временную, как выше указали), какую у нее колонку нужно перенести в первую таблицу и по какому условию.

Comment: А как будет выглядеть запрос?

Comment: ошибся с названием - `update with join` , в интернете много примеров, сам запрос `UPDATE zakazy set product = p.some_field from product p where zakazy.id = p.key_id`